# Unable to autoresize columns in ListView/GridView using an attached property

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview, attached-properties

I have the following Attached Property:-

```
public partial class GridViewProperties
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DoAutoSizeColumnsProperty =
                DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DoAutoSizeColumns", 
                typeof(bool), 
                typeof(GridViewProperties),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, 
                                                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault | 
                                                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure |
                                                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange |
                                                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentArrange |
                                                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentMeasure |
                                                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
                                                DoAutoSizeColumnsChanged));

    public static bool GetDoAutoSizeColumns(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(DoAutoSizeColumnsProperty);
    }

    public static void SetDoAutoSizeColumns(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(DoAutoSizeColumnsProperty, value);
    }

    private static void DoAutoSizeColumnsChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var gv = obj as GridView;

        if (gv == null)
            return;

        if (e.NewValue != null && (bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            AutoSizeColumns(gv.Columns);
            SetDoAutoSizeColumns(gv, false);
            gv.InvalidateProperty(GridView.ColumnCollectionProperty);
        }
    }
    private static void AutoSizeColumns(GridViewColumnCollection gvcc)
    {

        // same code as double clicking column gripper
        foreach (var gvc in gvcc)
        {
            // if already set to auto, toggle it so that we can re-run width="auto"
            //if (double.IsNaN(gvc.Width))
            gvc.Width = gvc.ActualWidth;
            // now do it                
            gvc.Width = double.NaN;
            //gvc.InvalidateProperty(GridViewColumn.WidthProperty);
            //gvc.ClearValue(GridViewColumn.WidthProperty);
        }
    } 
}
```

I use it in XAML in the following fashion:

```
<Style x:Key="AutoColumnStyle" TargetType="ListView">
        <Setter Property="View">
            <Setter.Value>
                 <GridView infra:GridViewProperties.AutoSizeColumns="{Binding Path=DataContext.DoAutoSizeColumns, Source={x:Reference uc}}">
                    <GridViewColumn  Width="auto"   Header="Title"  CellTemplate="{StaticResource Name}" />
                     <GridViewColumn Width="auto"   Header="First" CellTemplate="{StaticResource First}"/>                         
                     <GridViewColumn Width="auto"   Header="Last" CellTemplate="{StaticResource Last}"/>                         
                 </GridView>
             </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

The abaove is in UserControl.Resources.

The rest of the XAML is:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Names}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
              SelectionMode="Single"
              x:Name="ListViewContracts"
              KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue"
              KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" 
              Style="{StaticResource AutoColumnStyle}" 
          >
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle >
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ListViewItemContainerStyle}" TargetType="ListViewItem">                
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>                
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

(I have tried this with no Width="auto" too).

Whenever I set DoAutoSizeColumns = true in my ViewModel I see everything work as expected in the attached property except what it is desgined for that is the gridview columns are not resized according to the largest item in that column (even though I see gv.Width toggled from and to double.Nan which is how resize is meant to work).

As you can see I have tried a number of variations in the attached property mostly commented out including adding in all the FrameworkPoprertyMetadataOptions and trying various InvalidatePoperty attempts but also UIPropertyMetadata too (and DynamicResource too).

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

This attached property works in other GridViews the only difference I can see here is that - I need to switch GridViews in the ListView which was not indicated above -but the key difference is that I inject as a style rather than directly. (On second thoughts this may not be the case since the firs item in a column in these other GridViews is always the largest item).

Comment: I have an answer but cannot post it for another 4 hours

Answer (score 0):

It was to do with the injection of a style.

I had two different GridViews switched by a boolean and used a DataTrigger to inject the alternate one and AutoSizeColumns worked fine on that altererate GridView! So I made both styles be injected by a DataTrigger rather having the default set by just a setter as in the XAML above.

As to why this is case I would be interested in finding out. At least I have a fully MVVM way of autosizing columns which I have not seen in other SO answers.

(BTW I have other attached properties that do not need me to manually trigger the autosize, I just wrote this version to identify the problem).